# How to measure the amount of uncertainty

Tags: probability-theory, random, information-theory

What are the possible measures of uncertainty for a discrete variable *X=(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>)*, where values are defined by the alphabet  - *x<sub>i</sub> ∈ A*, given probabilities *p(x<sub>i</sub>) = P(X = x<sub>i</sub>)* change over time?

E.g. consider time interval T∈( t<sub>0</sub>, t<sub>n</sub>) where t<sub>0</sub> < t<sub>1</sub> <... < t<sub>n</sub> 
1) t = t<sub>0</sub> < t<sub>1</sub>: P = { p(x<sub>0</sub>), p(x<sub>1</sub>), ..., p(x<sub>2</sub>) } 
2) t = t<sub>1</sub> < t<sub>2</sub>: P = { p(x<sub>0</sub>)', p(x<sub>1</sub>)', ..., p(x<sub>2</sub>)' } 
3) ...

Where p(x<sub>i</sub>) ≠ p(x<sub>i</sub>)' and  Δt = t<sub>i</sub> -  t<sub>i-1</sub> → 0

Comment: A more careful formulation of the question is required: if $X$ is a random variable, the expression $x\in X$ is mysterious.

Comment: I imagine that the best you can do is to give a measure of uncertainty for a fixed time, eg the variance for given $p(x_i)$. I suppose you could integrate these expressions across time, though it's not quite clear what that would mean.

Comment: @Didier I tried to update the question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: My comment still applies: a random variable is not the set of the values it takes.

Comment: Like @Chris said (but considering also entropy, apart from variance, as a standard measure of uncertainty).

Comment: @Didier, I have confused you with the word *random*, sorry for that, what I meant is a discrete variable that takes values from an alphabet with a given probability which change over time.

Comment: @Didier, I am not too sure which entropy I can apply, shall I make entropy function of time as well?

Comment: @oleksii You seem to have put the word *random* under the rug (in your context, I do not know what is a variable which is not a random variable) but the same objection still fully applies: a random variable X **is not** its image set A but a function from a probability space (Omega,F,P) to A. // The entropy of a discrete distribution $p$ is $H(p)=-\sum_xp(x)\log p(x)$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition. If the distribution p(t) changes over time t, you might consider the integral of H(p(t)).

Comment: @Didier I think this answers my question, could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a random variable X is not its image set A but a (measurable) function from a probability space (Ω,F,P) to a (measurable) set A. In your context, A={x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>} and the distribution of the random variable X is characterized by a collection of nonnegative real numbers p(x<sub>1</sub>), p(x<sub>2</sub>), ..., and p(x<sub>n</sub>) summing to 1.

As @Chris said, your first task is to define a measure of uncertainty, suitable in your context. In other words, for every distribution p one must define a number U(p).

Two options are to use [the variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable)

> U(p)=M<sub>2</sub>(p)-M(p)<sup>2</sup> with M<sub>2</sub>(p)=∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> p(x<sub>i</sub>) and M(p)=∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub> p(x<sub>i</sub>),

or [the entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition)

> U(p)=−∑<sub>i</sub> p(x<sub>i</sub>) log p(x<sub>i</sub>).

Both quantities are nonnegative, and zero only in the degenerate case when p(x<sub>i</sub>)=1 for a given i and p(x<sub>j</sub>)=0 for every other j.

Once the functional U is defined, if the distribution p changes with time t, one might consider the integral

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>T</sup> U(p(t)) dt

of the functional U applied to p(t) on the time interval of interest.